# Cannot push to remote git, HTTP 403 error

Tags: git

Problem is not related with previously asked question which was about problem with authentication. In this case I am able to authenticate but next something goes wrong..

While I have set `remote origin` as:

```
git remote set-url origin https://developer@10.10.1.32/gitblit-1.6.0/r/RemovalTool.git
```

And then:

```
 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push -u origin master
```

I am getting

```
> [root@devel]# git push -u origin master error: The requested URL
> returned error: 403 while accessing
> https://developer@10.10.1.32/gitblit-1.6.0/r/RemovalTool.git/info/refs
> 
> fatal: HTTP request failed [root@devel]# GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
> -u origin master
> * Couldn't find host 10.10.1.32 in the .netrc file; using defaults
> * About to connect() to proxy 10.10.1.31 port 3128 (#0)
> *   Trying 10.10.1.31... * Connected to 10.10.1.31 (10.10.1.31) port 3128 (#0)
> * Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to 10.10.1.32:443
> > CONNECT 10.10.1.32:443 HTTP/1.1 Host: 10.10.1.32:443 User-Agent: git/1.7.1 Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache
> 
> < HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden < Server: squid < Mime-Version: 1.0 < Date:
> Mon, 20 Jul 2015 06:27:19 GMT < Content-Type: text/html <
> Content-Length: 3153 < X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0 < Vary:
> Accept-Language < Content-Language: en < X-Cache: MISS from proxy-vpn
> < X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from proxy-vpn:3128 < Proxy-Connection:
> keep-alive <
> * The requested URL returned error: 403
> * Connection #0 to host 10.10.1.31 left intact
> * Couldn't find host 10.10.1.32 in the .netrc file; using defaults
> * About to connect() to proxy 10.10.1.31 port 3128 (#1)
> *   Trying 10.10.1.31... * Connected to 10.10.1.31 (10.10.1.31) port 3128 (#1)
> * Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to 10.10.1.32:443
> > CONNECT 10.10.1.32:443 HTTP/1.1 Host: 10.10.1.32:443 User-Agent: git/1.7.1 Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma: no-cache
> 
> < HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden < Server: squid < Mime-Version: 1.0 < Date:
> Mon, 20 Jul 2015 06:27:20 GMT < Content-Type: text/html <
> Content-Length: 3153 < X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0 < Vary:
> Accept-Language < Content-Language: en < X-Cache: MISS from proxy-vpn
> < X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from proxy-vpn:3128 < Proxy-Connection:
> keep-alive <
> * The requested URL returned error: 403
> * Connection #1 to host 10.10.1.31 left intact error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
> https://developer@10.10.1.32/gitblit-1.6.0/r/RemovalTool.git/info/refs
> 
> fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I am 100% sure that the password I have provided is correct. I am also able to establish telnet connection to `10.10.1.32 443`, so connection problem is not a think in this case.. Can anyone give me a hint what Am I missing?

Comment: if You read carefully You would notice that duplicate You are reffering to was releted to being unable to authenticate (VERBOSE 401 error) while I can authenticate

Answer (score 0):

It`s look like the owner of git-repository is not added you to collaborators!

Comment: I am the owner and I have set permision for `developer` account equal to the owner..